# basic use of constructor XSSFWorkbook()

Tags: apache, constructor, apache-poi

I want to enable my class to access and get information from an excel workbook using apache POI.  I am using:

```
XSSFWorkbook mybook = new XSSFWorkbook("Filepath");
```

But this throws "unhandled exception type ioexception".

I am sure it's something very obvious, but I don't understand why this isn't working.  The constructor should just be 
XSSFWorkbook() according to the apachePOI documentation.  So I know I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: did you even catch exception?

Comment: yes I added that afterwards and it still wasn't working.  I ended up using another approach and now am able to access my workbook.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just reading an `xlsx` file.

```
        try {

            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(path));
            Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

            //rest of your logic

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Make sure that file on filePath exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *read* an excel file, that file must exist and be readable. I doubt that you have an excel file called "Filepath" in your current working directory, which is why you get the `IOException`.

Change the path to something pointing to a real excel file.

As an aside, you should be using the new SS Usermodel, so your code would become:

```
Workbook mybook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("/path/to/file.xlsx"));
```

Comment: That was poor notation on my part, I was trying to represent that there I had written the relative path of an existing file.